# Excel: Check value and copy color from a cell

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I feel like this question has been asked before, but I am just not really understanding the solutions. I would like to know how to check the values of some cells and copy the colors of those that match to another cell. I have a worksheet that looks like this:

```
   A        B           C       D               E               F
 1 Type     Location    Cell    PairType        PairLocation    PairCell
 2 EX3      1           A1      EX2             1               F3
 3 EX4      1           B2      EX3             1               G3
 4 EX2      1           F3      EX3             1               A1
```

Some of the values in A, B and C have different colors to mark them as special (background colors, not font colors). I need to take the values from column D, find the match in A and then if/when I find a match, copy the background colors from A, B and C to the background of D, E and F. If I find a D to A match (like row 2, column D to row 4, column A) then the E/F values will also match the B/C values (as shown above), so I don't have to worry about overwriting any values. I am not really fluent in Excel-ese so when I read a solution like this:

```
Function BGCol(MRow As Integer, MCol As Integer)  As Integer
   BGCol = Cells(MRow, MCol).Interior.ColorIndex  
End Function
```

I am not really sure what I am getting myself into. 
Can anyone offer a solution and an explaination?

Comment: `I am not really fluent in Excel-ese` Are you at all familiar with VBA, because that Function is a VBA solution. I don't even think you can get away without a VBA solution on this one.

Comment: I am sorta kinda familiar with visual basic. As in I wrote 2 or 3 small programs in it a year ago but it was never actually in reference to an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. It could be made more efficient, but it will definitely get you started.

Place this in a standard module and run the code (F5 or F8 to step through it). Let me know if you need more guidance.

```
Sub CheckColors()

Dim rng As Range

For Each cel In Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Set rng = Columns(1).Find(cel, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Interior.ColorIndex
        cel.Offset(, 1).InteriorColorIndex = rng.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
        cel.Offset(, 2).InteriorColorIndex = rng.Offset(, 2).Interior.ColorIndex

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: When I try to use this code the line xlUp gives a Compile Error: Invalid qualifier. Could you explain xlUp and xlWhole? Perhaps I don't understand the error because I don't quite understand what those are.

Comment: I've edited my code. I had the wrong syntax in there. `End(xlUp)` will go the end, in any direction, of a contiguous range (be it blank or with data). So if you have data in cells B1:B10, and all blanks from B10:B50 and you type Range("B20").End(xlUp), it will take you to B10. `xlWhole` is used in the `Find` method, it tells exact to look for an exact match, as opposed to the search text existing in any part `xlPart` of the cell. Use the Find function in Excel, to explore this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ReColour()

Dim rStart As Range, lRow1 As Long, lRow2 As Long, lRows As Long, sFind As String

Set rStart = Sheet1.Range("A1")
lRows = rStart.Offset(65000, 0).End(xlUp).Row - rStart.Row

For lRow1 = 1 To lRows
    sFind = rStart.Offset(lRow1, 3).Value
    For lRow2 = 1 To lRows
        If rStart.Offset(lRow2, 0).Value = sFind Then
            rStart.Offset(lRow1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = rStart.Offset(lRow2, 0).Interior.ColorIndex
            rStart.Offset(lRow1, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = rStart.Offset(lRow2, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
            rStart.Offset(lRow1, 5).Interior.ColorIndex = rStart.Offset(lRow2, 2).Interior.ColorIndex
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Sorry no time to explain right now, but I think this'll do it. You should really use something better than magic column numbers 3,4,5 etc but this is a quickndirty solution.